# Не открывается страница, опубликованная через github pages

Tags: html, css, github-pages

https://github.com/KostyaPapushnikov/Practice_1

Публикую репозиторий через github pages, но при попытке открыть страницу https://kostyapapushnikov.github.io/Practice_1/ появляется ошибка 404

[image]

Что не так?

Comment: добавь скриншот страницы настроек твоего репозитория

Answer (score 4):

Как указано в ошибке: для корневых урлов должен присутствовать файл `index.html`.

В репозитории такого файла нет.

Однако есть файл `main.html`.

И по ссылке: https://kostyapapushnikov.github.io/Practice_1/main.html

все открывается.